# Its difficult to learn English because English and grammar are different,

Tags: grammar

Because English and grammar are different, 한국어가 이게 맞나요? 영어와 문법이 다르기 때문에 한국어는 어렵다

Comment: Hi tony - sorry, I'm not quite clear what the question is here. Are you trying to make a Korean translation of "It's difficult to learn English Because English and grammar are different"?

Comment: would you mind making this question clearer?

Comment: Uh, sorry, I don't even get the question. How did this get 5 upvotes?

Comment: Just a note: “Korean is difficult (to learn) because it has different grammar from English.” translates to “한국어는 영어와 문법이 다르기 때문에 (배우기) 어렵다.”